# MySQL full text index underscore

Tags: mysql, localization, full-text-search, collation, stop-words

I have a problem with MySQL's full text index, it treats underscore as part of a word (why? dunno).
This is the string I have in my table, `VA_-_Some_Album`

And this is the query for it:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `mytable`
WHERE
 MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('+Some* +Album*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `sdate` DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

MySQL returns an empty set for this query, unless I change it to `+*Some*` since the underscore is part of the word (`_Some` instead of `Some`). This is not good for me, since when adding the extra asterisk (*) the plus sign stops functioning and I don't get the "AND" done.

I tried to change the charset definition, and rebuild the full-text index but nothing.

Any ideas? changing the way the string is stored is not up to me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear with your question but take a look here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

there they explain the differences between _, +, *, -, <>, etc In Boolean Mode

Comment: An underscore is used as part of a word, not an operator. I want it to be used a word separator (\b, \s etc)

Comment: if you add \\b I think youll be able to search \b, just add a \before (or two slash I'm not sure)

Comment: MySQL uses "_some" as a word, and I want it to use it without the underscore, like this "some". No, I was just using a REGEX anchor to explain.